# JQuery - Sorting DOM From Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several Objects that contain a reference to DOM elements:

```
var liObjs = [new Li($el1, price), new Li($el2, price), new Li($el3, price)]

// Li Model
function Li($element, price){
 var self = this;

 self.price = price; 
 self.$element = $element;
}

// My DOM Looks like this:
<ul>
 <li>Price: $3</li>
 <li>Price: $1</li>
 <li>Price: $2</li>
</ul>
```

And and I need them sorted by price based on the objects in `liObjs`.

I've managed to sort `liObjs` based on each objects price property but I cannot render them in order for the life of me. Please help.

Note:
The `<li>s` are already created in DOM but I need to reorder them when the page loads.

Comment: There's no jQuery code here. Is `$el1` a DOM element or the jQuery object containing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non jQuery Way**

```
// Remove existing elements from the parent node.
var parent = liObjs[0].$element.parentNode;

while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
  parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
}

// Assuming you have already sorted the array
// you can simply loop through them and add them

liObjs.forEach(function(item) {
  parent.appendChild(item.$element);
});
```

**jQuery Way**

```
$(liObjs[0].$element)
  .parent()
  .empty()
  .append(liObjs.map(function(item) {
    return item.$element;
  }));
```

Here's a CodePen showing how this works.
http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/NpavgZ?editors=1010

Comment: wouldn't parent.html(''); be faster?

Comment: I am pretty sure `parent.html('');` destroys the `li` nodes. If you call `.removeChild()` they remain in memory which is nice because you maintain a reference to them in your `liObjs` array.

Also... I doubt you'll notice any difference in performance.

Comment: @jessegavin I don't think so. As long as you have references to them, the nodes still exist, they just get detacthed.